# CMake library not found

Tags: cmake

I try to run the makefile that using cmake produced. It generate an error

```
ld: library not found for -lhello
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

the file directory is:
[image]

the cmakelists.txt is:
[image]

the main.c file is:
[image]

the ERROR:
[image]

I think I set the right directory. How to solve this ERROR?

Comment: "I think I set the right directory." - You haven't set any directory for **linker**; `include_directories()` sets directories for *compiler*. Have you seen this generic question about library linking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library/10550334#10550334?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I try to add the link_directories(), but still get the same error.

Comment: Yes, sometimes `link_directories` don't work as expected. Try the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10550334/3440745): it is more scored than the accepted one.

Comment: The second answer worked! well done!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake link to external library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library)

Comment: @Tsyvarev I find the reason why `link_directories` not work. Because the `link_directories` must set before the `add_executable`

Answer (score 8):

CMake has a system if you want to link libraries. For many standard libraries we have cmake modules which will allow you to use the [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) command. This will set some variables for include directories and libraries. If there is no such thing for your library you can use [find_path](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_path.html) for the include files and [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) to search for a library.

Here is what you could do (untested, just out of my head):

```
add_executable(main main.c)

target_include_directories(
    PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/hello
)

find_library (
    HELLO_LIB
    NAMES hello libhello # what to look for
    HINTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib" # where to look
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH # do not search system default paths
)

# check if we found the library
message(STATUS "HELLO_LIB: [${HELLO_LIB}]")

if (NOT HELLO_LIB)
    message(SEND_ERROR "Did not find lib hello")
endif

target_link_libraries(main
    ${HELLO_LIB}
)
```

Use `message` to debug your cmake files. If you define the library in cmake as well you can link directly against the cmake target.

Answer (score 1):

When your library isn't in a standard path liking `/usr/lib`, you should use `link_directories()` in your `CMakeLists.txt` to specify a non-standard library path which contains your library. Notice that you MUST put your `link_directories()` ahead of `add_executable()` as the following shows:

```
link_directories(../../lib)
add_executable(newhello main.c)
include_directories(../../include)
target_link_libraries(newhello hello)
```

Comment: Thanks the God. Save my time. I just adjust the line position of link_directories() as you said. Then it compiled succeed.